# Dynamically modify audio src and then play is prohibited in Safari?

Tags: javascript, iframe, safari

This is my code. If I directly write the audio's src before playing, it can play normally. However, if I dynamically modify the audio src before playing, an error will be reported on Safari.

```
<audio :src="audioSrc" ref="mAudio"></audio>

      this.audioSrc = 'https://myaudiourl.wav'
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        console.log('play')
        this.$refs.mAudio.play()
        // got error
      })
```

error message

```
Unhandled Promise Rejection: NotAllowedError: The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission.
```

Comment: You use `:src`. But that is not a valid HTML attribute…